# In groovy, how to filter list when list is null?

Tags: groovy, stream

Here is my code:
[image]
When getListsByModelName(modelName) return null, there is a NullPointerException, how can I determin getListsByModelName return value is not null with stream?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, where text would do.  We can not search in
or copy from screenshots. Use groovys null-safe-navigator `?.`.
Sidenote: you could replace all the `Map.of` with map literals.

Comment: simply don't use stream API while in Groovy (and actually everywhere else)